# DB2 database accesing through client

Tags: db2

my scenario is just like this.

I need to install DB2 in one VM and create databases on it. From an other VM i need to acess the DB through client. Can any one help me by saying the process.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the client software and then you need to catalog the node and the database (see "catalog tcpip node" and "catalog database" in the DB2 documentation).

Comment: data studio client is the client which said right? i am not aware of it.